# How should I define result?

Tags: python

I am running the below code and getting result not defined error.

```py
inp = input("Enter the value to convert = ")
degree = int(inp[:-1])
i_conversion = inp[-1]
if i_conversion.upper == "C":
    result = int(round((9 * degree) / 5 + 32))
    o_conversion = "Fahrenheit"
elif i_conversion.upper == "F":
    result = int(round((degree - 32) * 5 / 9))
    o_conversion = "Celsius"

print("The temp is", result)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack-Overflow.
Please use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for your code with right indentation. Also please copy paste us your actual error message

Comment: You should probably avoid a traceback when the input is neither C nor F.

Answer (score 1):

`str.upper` is a function not an attribute; it requires brackets after it. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper)

```
inp = input("Enter the value to convert = ")
degree = int(inp[:-1])
i_conversion = inp[-1]
if i_conversion.upper() == "C":
    result = int(round((9 * degree) / 5 + 32))
    o_conversion = "Fahrenheit"
elif i_conversion.upper() == "F":
    result = int(round((degree - 32) * 5 / 9))
    o_conversion = "Celsius"

print("The temp is", result)
```

Comment: @CDJB ,  Using upper function without brackets not causes (not defined error), it just return object place in memory  which lead to get wrong value,not throw error.

Comment: Correct, but treating it as an attribute in this way skips the if statements and goes straight to the print function, in which `result` is undefined.

Comment: @CDJB He got not defined error . He didn't define result variable at all , you just miss while reading question, i edited the answer.

Comment: result can be defined within the if statement just fine; as long as one of the if conditions fires this solution works fine. I’ve rejected the edit as it confuses the problem.